# Shiro throws an UnavailableSecurityManagerException in custom JSON serialiser

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jackson, jersey-2.0, shiro

I'm working on a REST API of a TomEE 7 based web app, which uses Shiro 1.3.2 for security. When an API request comes in, a `SecurityManager` and a `Subject` are created, and the latter is bound to a `SubjectThreadState`. I can call `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` anywhere in the endpoint code and the subject is always available.

However, problems arise when I try to do the same inside my custom JSON serialiser. It only serialises specific fields in some classes, so I register it on a per-field basis using this annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MySerialiser.class)
Long myRelatedItemId;
```

I wrote my serialiser based on [the example code on this page under "2.7. @JsonSerialize"](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations). The serialiser needs to perform a cache lookup, and for that it has to have a Shiro subject. There is none because, thanks to the annotation above, I don't call the serialiser manually; instead Jersey calls it. This exception gets thrown (**clarification:** when I try to run `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` from the serialiser code):

```
org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
    at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager(SecurityUtils.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.<init>(Subject.java:627)
    at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject(SecurityUtils.java:56)
```

I have confirmed that everything works if I call something like `ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString()` manually from the API endpoint code. However, that is definitely not the proper way to do it, because then the endpoint would effectively send and receive strings instead of the objects they are meant to handle.

I don't understand much about the inner workings of Shiro or Jackson, but it seems like the serialisation is being performed inside another thread, where Shiro's `SubjectThreadState` doesn't exist. Although if threading really is the cause, then I cannot see why `Thread.currentThread().getName()` returns the same value both inside and outside the serialiser, as does `Thread.currentThread().getId()`.

I have tried a vast number of things to no avail, including:

- Upgrading to Shiro 1.4.0.
- Upgrading Jackson from 2.7.5 to 2.9.7.
- Saving the `SecurityManager` instance that is created at the start of the API call inside a static `ThreadLocal` variable of the serialiser class.
- Writing my own implementation of `MessageBodyWriter` which, not surprisingly, is called in exactly the same fashion.
- Setting the `staticSecurityManagerEnabled` parameter to `true` in the `ShiroFilter` configuration in my `web.xml`.

Can anyone suggest how I could make the `SecurityManager` (or `Subject`) visible to the serialiser, when it's running in a thread not started by my code (**clarification:** or, otherwise running in parallel and started by Jersey, as far as I can tell)? Thanks in advance.

### Update:

This stack trace was taken inside the serialiser:

```
<mypackage>.MySerializer.serialize()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue()
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo()
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo()
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo()
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo()
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo()
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed()
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run()
```

This one was taken in our interceptor class where the `Subject` is created and bound:

```
<mypackage>.MySecurityInterceptor.createSession()
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0()
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed()
org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record()
org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke()
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke()
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed()
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod()
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod()
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke()
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke()
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy279.getEntity()
org.openapitools.api.impl.MyApiServiceImpl.getEntity()
org.openapitools.api.MyApi.getEntity()
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0()
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply()
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run()
```

There are 46 more calls that are identical in both traces after that last line, so I excluded them. They contain a bunch of `org.apache.catalina.core` and `org.glassfish.jersey`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Shiro's [Subject Thread Association doc](https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#thread-association)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already read that page. Could you provide some more details about how to use this info? I don't have `Subject` inside the serialiser, and when it runs, it's not a `Callable` or `Runnable` created by me. For what it's worth, the example under "Manual Association" is very similar to what our code does.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a different thread, and I don't know where it starts. All I have at the moment are two stack traces: one taken inside the serialiser and the other taken in the interceptor class where the `Subject` is created and bound. I will add these stack traces to my question.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see part of the problem. Can you explain what/how your Jackson mapper requires a subject?  Are you marshaling an object in a session or something?

Comment: The context is that the field which I call `myRelatedItemId` above must be serialised as not a `Long` but a `String`, namely the UUID of the related item. To be able to read that item's UUID, I need to fetch the item from a cache. Every customer has their own dedicated cache, and in order to use the caches, I have to know which customer is in question. I can't see a way to pass this information into the serialiser, but if I could call `SecurityUtils.getSubject()`, that would provide everything I need.

Comment: Let me rephrase that last bit: The cache lookup routine itself tries to call `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` to get the customer as well as the user, but this throws the `UnavailableSecurityManagerException`.

Comment: Sounds like you also have a chicken vs egg issue here too. You need the subject to lookup the session cache, but you need the cache to load the subject?  My guess is you are going to need to decouple the two. Or create some Jackson post processor that handles the object after it is unmarshalled.  I'm also not sure what order your unmarshelling happens vs the security filter processing. Is it possible make the Shiro filter be processed sooner?

Comment: I don't see the chicken and egg. I don't need the cache for loading the subject, because the subject isn't stored in a cache. I'm having a hard time trying to describe the situation, because I don't really understand how everything works with Shiro. Thank you for being patient. Could you give me some guidelines on how to determine whether the Shiro filter could be processed sooner?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  It depends where the Jackson processing happens, I don't know if it is happening in a Servlet Filter or an Interceptor. But the Shrio Fitler _should_ be configured to run before the Jackson processing happens. My guess is the oposite is true.